# read json file from resources

Tags: quarkus, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to read json file that located in documents folder into resources file in quarkus.
here is my code:

```
 try(InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("documents/helloWorldDocument.json")) {
                // Retrieve the JSON document and put into a string/object map
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> documentMapType =
                        new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {};
//
                Map<String, Object> document = mapper.readValue(
                        new File(inputStream.toString()),
                        documentMapType);


                // Use builder methods in the SDK to create the directive.
                RenderDocumentDirective renderDocumentDirective = RenderDocumentDirective.builder()
                        .withToken("helloWorldToken")
                        .withDocument(document)
                        .build();

                // Add the directive to a responseBuilder.
                responseBuilder.addDirective(renderDocumentDirective);

                // Tailor the speech for a device with a screen.
                speechText.append(" You should now also see my greeting on the screen.");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new AskSdkException("Unable to read or deserialize the hello world document", e);
            }
```

but getting exception. really appreciate if anyone could help.
(I'm implementing APL for an alexa skill)

Comment: Could you share what the error is? That will help people help you. 

It would also be useful to see how you're constructing the classloader, since I suspect that's where the problem is coming from. 

Is this in dev mode, or running the tests with maven?

Comment: ohh, my problem was about reading a json file from resources file in Quarkus. which resolved and have mentioned here in answers part. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

You can create a **quarkus component** to read JSON files (at least as a list of a known objects) with something like:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.CollectionType;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Singleton
public class JsonFileReader {
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Inject
    public JsonFileReader(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    public <T> List<T> readFile(File file, Class<T> elementClass) throws IOException {
        CollectionType listType =
                mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, elementClass);
        return mapper.readValue(file, listType);
    }
}
```

To use it from another component, just inject it and use it:

```
    @Inject
    JsonFileReader jsonFileReader;

    ...


    
    public void useObjects() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        File file = ??? // Get the file you want to read...
        List<KnownClass> objects = jsonFileReader.readFile(file, KnownClass.class);

        ...
    }
```

A more detailed description can be found in this article: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-linkedhashmap-cannot-be-cast

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot, I solve this:

```
 try {
            File file = new File(
                    Objects.requireNonNull(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("helloWorldDocument.json")).getFile()
            );
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> documentMapType =
                    new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
                    };
            Map<String, Object> document = mapper.readValue(
                    new File(file.toString()),
                    documentMapType);
            RenderDocumentDirective renderDocumentDirective = RenderDocumentDirective.builder()
                    .withToken("helloWorldToken")
                    .withDocument(document)
                    .build();
            responseBuilder.addDirective(renderDocumentDirective);
            speechText.append(" You should now also see my greeting on the screen.");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new AskSdkException("Unable to read or deserialize the hello world document", e);
        }
```